# Bitbucket scriptrunner API endpoints to automate?

Tags: bitbucket

I'm looking for Bitbucket scriptrunner API endpoints to automate enabling the merge checks available via this plugin in Bitbcuket.

Is there any documentation or steps?

Otherwise, I use the API's for other automations in Bitbucket here:

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.2.3/bitbucket-git-rest.html

I tried with this but doesn't seem to work:

requests.get('https://stash.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/project-x/repos/test/scriptrunner')

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Script REST Endpoints https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.4/bitbucket/rest-endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks @hrom; I had seen this but not greatly helpful or easy to use. I'll keep trying.